# Perl: warning: Setting locale failed

Tags: perl

I have problems when installing the tool and performing upgrades in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Please assist me

```
    Fetched 6738 kB in 1min 19s (85.1 kB/s)                                        
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en",
    LC_ALL = "en_GB.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "id_ID.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "id_ID.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "id_ID.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "id_ID.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "id_ID.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "id_ID.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "id_ID.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "id_ID.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "id_ID.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^(.*?)(\\)?\${ <-- HERE ([^{}]+)}(.*)$/ at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Question.pm line 72.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\${ <-- HERE ([^}]+)}/ at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Config.pm line 30.
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)


sudo apt-get install locales
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.22) but 2.13+git20120306-12.1 is to be installed
         Recommends: libc6-i686
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

sudo apt-get install libc6-i686
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libc6-i686 is a virtual package provided by:
  libc6 2.19-0ubuntu6.7 [Not candidate version]
  libc6 2.19-0ubuntu6 [Not candidate version]

E: Package 'libc6-i686' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: `libc6-i686`? What package repositories did you set up? Also, your locale settings look a bit weird with all of `en`, `en_US`, `en_GB` and `id_ID` present in one category or another.

Comment: I use a local repository Indonesia, i from Indonesia so obvious that I wear id.

Comment: Sure, but what about the mixture with all the other locales thrown in there?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
locale-gen id_ID.UTF-8
```

However, some PPA might not be installed unless `LC_ALL=C` sets, e.g. [PPA for PHP](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php).

Comment: locales seem to be erased so I can not install it again. What can I install via live USB?
The program 'locale-gen' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install locales

Comment: You might be able to install "locales" to get locale-gen via `apt-get install -locales`.  If you need to reinstall it, add `--reinstall` to it.

Comment: previously I could not install because of dependency and should upgrade libc6 now been solved thanks sir for your help.